# Python - oauth2 - linkedin API

Tags: python, oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to follow some companies registered on LinkedIn through python code and as per [LinkedIn API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-follow-and-suggestions)  I need to use **oauth2 - POST** method to follow a company.

My queries are below:

1. How to specify a particular company name via python code to follow a company?
2. Can someone advise the python code for this?

My code is below:

```
oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)
signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
http_method    = "POST"
http_handler   = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler  = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

def linkedinreq(url, method, parameters):
          req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                            token=oauth_token,
                                            http_method=http_method,
                                            http_url=url, 
                                            parameters=parameters)

          req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)
          req.to_postdata()

def fetchsamples():
          url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies"

          parameters = []
          response = linkedinreq(url, "POST", parameters)

fetchsamples()
```

Answer (score 8):

The python modules `python-linkedin` and `python-linkedin-v2` are outdated. Thus, I suggest you to use the `requests_oauthlib` module instead.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix

# In case the `redirect_url` does not implement https     
import os                                                   
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1' 

# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = '<the client id you get from linkedin>'
client_secret = '<the client secret you get from linkedin>'
redirect_url = '<authorized redirect URL from LinkedIn config>'

# OAuth endpoints given in the LinkedIn API documentation (check for updates)
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

# Authorized Redirect URL (from LinkedIn config)
linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_url)
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)

# Redirect user to LinkedIn for authorization
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
                     authorization_response=redirect_response)

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~')
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Where and how to get the client_id and client_secret from? Suppose if I want to practice fetching my own LinkedIn account info with this ethical procedure?

Comment: I would add the following to the authorization_url:

authorization_url += "&scope=r_liteprofile"

Comment: But what do I need to do to automatically pass the redirect_response without having to input manually as input?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use [`python-linkedin`](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin) wrapper.

Example code to search for the companies:

```
from linkedin import linkedin

CONSUMER_KEY = 'your key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'your secret'
USER_TOKEN = 'your token'
USER_SECRET = 'your user secret'
RETURN_URL = ''

# Instantiate the developer authentication class
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                          USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, 
                                                          RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

# Pass it in to the app...
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

print application.search_company(selectors=[{'companies': ['name', 'universal-name', 'website-url']}],
                                 params={'keywords': 'apple microsoft'})
```

To follow the company, use `follow_company()` method, see more information and examples [here](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin#company-api):

```
COMPANY_ID = 1035  # this you would get from the `search_company()`
application.follow_company(COMPANY_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I came across this link and used it. However, I want to know regarding POST in oauth2. I could not find good tutorial to understand this.